# How would I break down a word from input and apply it to a print function of key:value pairs of an established dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

### I want to translate a word that is input to be broken down into Morse code. My code works for the letter "a" and nothing else.

## dictionary

dic = {"A" : ".-", "B" : "-...","C" : "-.-.","D" : ".","E" : "..-.","F" : "..-.","G" : "--.","H" :"....",
"I" : "..", "J" : ".---", "K" : "-.-", "L" : ".-..", "M" : "--", "N" : "-.", "O" : "---", "P" : ".--.",
"Q" : "--.-", "R" : ".-.", "S" : "...", "T" : "-", "U" : "..-", "V" : "...-", "W" : ".--", "X" : "-..-",
"Y" : "-.--", "Z" : "--.."}

### code so far that is not working

```py
def Morse():
    bit = {}
    inp = str(input("Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):"))
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if len(inp) > 1:
            bit = list(inp.upper()) # converts input to letters
            for k in bit:
                if k == key:
                    print(k,value)
                    break
         elif inp.upper() == key:  # trying to apply both lower and uppercase of letters here
            bit = list(inp)
            print(bit,value)
         else:
            break
```

desired output with input function:

> Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):  ads

"a", "d", "s" : ".-", ".", "..."

Thanks for the input. I ended up figuring out what I wanted to do with:

```py
def Morse():
    bit = []
    inp = str(input("Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):"))
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if len(inp) > 1:
            bit = list(inp)
            spell = list(map(dic.get, bit))
            print(spell)
            break
```

Sorry for poor phrasing of the question. First time posting to stack and getting used to the interface.

Comment: you should explain what exactly is not working (what output do you get etc.)

Comment: I can't understand what you want as an output, can you explain more ?

Comment: Solved it using:
```python
def Morse():
    bit = []
    inp = str(input("Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):"))
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if len(inp) > 1:
            bit = list(inp)
            spell = list(map(dic.get, bit))
            print(spell)
            break
```
OUTPUT:
Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):ADS
['.-', '.', '...']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want but this code make sure that user input is only letters using `regex` and `while loop` then return a `list` of the conversion:

```
dic = {"A" : ".-", "B" : "-...","C" : "-.-.","D" : ".","E" : "..-.","F" : "..-.","G" : "--.","H" :"....", "I" : "..", "J" : ".---", "K" : "-.-", "L" : ".-..", "M" : "--", "N" : "-.", "O" : "---", "P" : ".--.", "Q" : "--.-", "R" : ".-.", "S" : "...", "T" : "-", "U" : "..-", "V" : "...-", "W" : ".--", "X" : "-..-", "Y" : "-.--", "Z" : "--.."}

import re
def Morse():
    lst=[]
    while True:
        inp=str(input("Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):"))
        if not re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", inp):
            print ("Error! Make sure you only use letters")
        else:
            break
    
    for i in inp:
        lst.append(dic[i.uppe()]
    return lst
Morse()
>>>ads
>>>['.-', '.', '...']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the dictionary, you can loop over the input itself.

```
def Morse():
    bit = {}
    #don't need to convert input to string as it is always string
    inp = input("Type what you would like converted to Morse code") 
    for letter in input:
        bit.update({letter:dic[letter.upper()]})
    print(bit)
```

or using dictionary comprehension

```
def Morse():
    inp = input("Type what you would like converted to Morse code") 
    bit = {letter:dic[letter.upper()] for letter in inp}
    print(bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done as a one-liner:

```py
def morse():
    print([dic[char] for char in list(input("Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):" ).upper()) if char in dic])
```

or in prettier format:

```py
def morse():
    print([
        dic[char]
        for char in list(input(
            "Type what you would like converted to Morse code (letters only):"
        ).upper())
        if char in dic
    ])
```